# Does there exist an upper bound on the Fourier coefficients of the reciprocal theta function $\frac {1}{\theta}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, special-functions

Define the theta function as
$$
\theta(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\gamma(x+n)^2}
$$
where $\gamma>0$. Clearly, $\theta$ is 1-periodic, non-zero and smooth. Therefore, the reciprocal map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{\theta(x)}$ is 1-periodic and smooth as well and can be expanded as a Fourier series:
$$
\frac{1}{\theta(x)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{2\pi i nx}.
$$
I'm interested in upper bounding the Fourier coefficients, i.e. I want to find a non-trivial map $f$ (with a fast decay) such that
$$
|a_n| \leq f(n).
$$
Are there any results in this direction? Thank you!

Comment: Your best bet would be to analytically or meromorphically continue $1/\theta(x)$ into a strip around the real axis and shift the contour of integration for the Fourier coefficients to either the upper half-plane or lower half-plane, depending on whether the frequency $n$ is positive or negative (i.e., use the saddle point method).

Comment: Please refer to A Characterization in the space of Convolution Operators- B.R.Nagaraj,Proc.AMS,Vol.94,July(1985)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@TerryTao](https://mathoverflow.net/users/766/terry-tao) stated correctly in the comments, a bound on the Fourier coefficients can be obtained by the saddle point method: The extension of $\frac 1 \theta$ to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$ has poles which are bounded away from the real axis. This implies that the Fourier coefficients of $\frac 1 \theta$ decay at least exponentially. In fact, the Fourier coefficients can be derived explicitly from which we can show that the decay is exactly exponentially:

First note, that your map $\theta$ is essentially the Jacobi theta function of third kind. Using Poisson's summation formula we have
$$
\theta(t) = \sqrt \frac \pi \gamma \sum_n \left ( e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{\gamma}} \right )^{n^2} e^{2\pi i n t} = \sqrt \frac \pi \gamma \vartheta_3(it, e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{\gamma}}).
$$
Hence, for $q = e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{\gamma}}$ and $z=it$ we have
$$
\frac 1 {\theta(t)} = \sqrt \frac \gamma \pi \frac 1 {\vartheta_3(z,q)}.
$$
In the paper *A.J.E.M. Janssen, Some Weyl-Heisenberg frame bound calculations,
Indagationes Mathematicae,
Volume 7, Issue 2,
1996,
Pages 165-183*, Janssen obtains on page 178 the Fourier expansion of $\frac 1 {\vartheta_3}$:

$$
\frac 1 {\vartheta_3(z,q)} = \frac 1 C \sum_k (-1)^k a_k e^{2ikz}
$$
$$
C = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} (-1)^n (2n+1)q^{(n+\frac 1 2)^2}
$$
$$
a_k = 2 \sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m q^{(m+\frac 1 2)(2|k|+m+\frac 1 2)}
$$
From the value $|k|$ in the exponent in the definition of $a_k$ it follows directly that the $a_k$'s decay exponentially assuming that $|q|<1$. Applying some trivial bounds on $a_k$ gives you the desired map $f$ so that $|a_k| \leq f(k)$.

To derive the above formula, Jenssen refers to an exercise in the book *Whittaker, E., & Watson, G. (1927). A Course of Modern Analysis (4th ed., Cambridge Mathematical Library)*. He essentially solves this exercise which leads to the above expression.

The above formula should agree with the one derived in the answer of [@მამუკა ჯიბლაძე](https://mathoverflow.net/users/41291/%E1%83%9B%E1%83%90%E1%83%9B%E1%83%A3%E1%83%99%E1%83%90-%E1%83%AF%E1%83%98%E1%83%91%E1%83%9A%E1%83%90%E1%83%AB%E1%83%94).

Comment: Great, that's it! It indeed agrees, taking into account the famous expansion $\prod_{n\geqslant1}(1-x^n)^3=\sum_{n\geqslant0}(-1)^n(2n+1)x^{n(n+1)}$. Except for one minor detail: $a_0$ must be replaced by $\frac12a_0$ (this is stated correctly in Whittaker & Watson, though, and my $c_0$ agrees with that too).

Answer (score 6):

By no means anything like a complete answer, but what I have is an empirical explicit formula for the coefficients $a_n$ which might be useful.

For $\theta$ itself,
$$
\theta(x)=\sqrt{\,\frac\pi\gamma\,}\ \left(1+2q\cos(2\pi x)+2q^4\cos(4\pi x)+2q^9\cos(6\pi x)+...+2q^{n^2}\cos(2\pi nx)+...\right),
$$
where $q=e^{-\frac{\pi^2}\gamma}$.

It seems that the following holds (checked in Mathematica to about 100th power of $q$):
$$
\frac1{\theta(x)}=\sqrt{\,\frac\gamma\pi\,}\ \frac1{\left((1-q^2)(1-q^4)(1-q^6)\cdots(1-q^{2n})\cdots\right)^3}\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\cos(2\pi n x),
$$
where
\begin{align*}
c_0=&\ \,1-q^2+q^6-q^{12}+...+(-1)^kq^{k(k+1)}+...,\\[.5ex]
c_1=-2&\left(q-q^5+q^{11}-q^{19}+...+(-1)^kq^{k(k+3)+1}+...\right),\\
c_2=2&\left(q^2-q^8+q^{16}-q^{26}+...+(-1)^kq^{k(k+5)+2}+...\right),\\
c_3=-2&\left(q^3-q^{11}+q^{21}-q^{33}+...+(-1)^kq^{k(k+7)+3}+...\right),\\
\cdots\\
c_n=(-1)^n\times2&\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kq^{k(k+2n+1)+n}
\end{align*}
Again empirically, these $c_n$ are of order $q^n$, but I do not know how to prove this. Here is the plot of their absolute values for $\gamma=100$:

[image]

Comment: Looks like some Ramanujan formula.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Whittaker & Watson (Example 14 on page 489) refer to the Mathematical Tripos of 1903 (see another answer).